# how can I implement common Bottom bar which behave like tab?

Tags: android, tabbar, blink

I have implement bottom bar as show below I achieved this using view flipper, its work perfect  but when I select any one item to start new activity, its blink because of activity change.

I want to make this bottom-bar behave like as tab in which only tab change and it wont blink activity.

[image]

Comment: use views instead of activities.

Answer (score 0):

Design a seperate layout with the Bottom images and their behavior  (like using selector etc to change state when you click on it ) and add that layout to your Activity XML using 
`<include> </include>` tag

Comment: I also made custom view which add in all layout.but it wont blink activity.

Comment: your tab like navigation can easily be handled with this include tag

Comment: thanks to reply .<include> </include> tag is good,after put this i need to implement all item click in all activity.but thats not good.
i want to make this bottom bar like tab.

Comment: yes thats a corn that you need  to implement click listener of each of the following